# What's a good way to mimic Web Forms RadioButtonList in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have View Model List like this:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
  int PersonId
  bool LikesIceCream
}
```

**The View will display a list of people and their preference to ice cream - like it or don't.**

I'm not sure how to construct the html in a way that I can use the RadioButtonFor HTML helper and properly pass the values back to the controller.  Simply creating RadioButtonFor's in a foreach loop doesn't help because they will have the same name.  Any idea how I can hook these values up with the model binder?

Thanks.

Comment: Why radio buttons? Why not checkboxes? Does that mean that you can have only one person that can like icecream? Seems pretty restrictive as application :-)

Comment: @Darin Sorry, there's a list of people records.

Comment: OK, and what do you want to do with this list on the view?

Comment: I just want to know how I can properly display the items using the strongly type model and be able to post the values back to the controller and retrieve them.

Comment: OK, I think I understood what you want. Checkout my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View model:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public bool LikesIceCream { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new[]
        {
            new PersonViewModel { PersonId = 1, LikesIceCream = true },
            new PersonViewModel { PersonId = 2, LikesIceCream = false },
            new PersonViewModel { PersonId = 3, LikesIceCream = true },
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<PersonViewModel> model)
    {
        // you will get what you need here inside the model
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

```
@model IEnumerable<PersonViewModel>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Editor template (`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/PersonViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model PersonViewModel

<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PersonId)
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.LikesIceCream, "true") Yes
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.LikesIceCream, "false") No
</div>
```

Comment: Oh nice, I think I understand.  So the EditorForModel is actually taking care of wiring up each radiobutton correctly so it can be properly bound to the model.  Thanks!